# How to run multiple .dat files in the same model with using flow control?

Tags: cplex, opl

I have a MIP model in CPLEX. I try to use a heuristic algorithm with using flow control. I need to use multiple ".dat" files and get the decision variables solution value in each time I solve the problem. I tried to used "addDataSource" but I have got no solution available error. When I try to solve without "addDataSource" I do not get this error. How can I handle with this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see several dat files in

https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/making-decision-optimization-simple-alex-fleischer/

```
{string} datFiles={"zoodat.dat","zoodat2.dat"};
    
    main
    {
      var source = new IloOplModelSource("zoodat.mod");
      var cplex = new IloCplex();
      var def = new IloOplModelDefinition(source);
     
      for(datFile in thisOplModel.datFiles)
      {
         writeln("with ",datFile);
         var opl1 = new IloOplModel(def,cplex);
         var data1=new IloOplDataSource(datFile);
          opl1.addDataSource(data1);
        
          opl1.generate();
          cplex.solve();
          opl1.postProcess();
          writeln();
   

        }

 }
 
 /*
 
 which gives
 
 with zoodat.dat
The minimum cost is 380
We will use 6 40 seats buses and 2 30 seats buses 
with zoodat2.dat
The minimum cost is 500
We will use 10 40 seats buses and 0 30 seats buses 
*/
```

Comment: Thank you! I have read your answers you wrote before for someone else's  question and I try it. It realy works to get Objective Function value but when i try to get my decision variable's solution value in the same model and main, It does not work. I get no solution error. I could not figure it out.

Comment: If after opl1.postProcess(); you write 
writeln("--> ",opl1.nbBus40," buses 40 seats"); you ll get --> 10 buses 40 seats